# Angular "required" attribute inside custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having the following issue with "required" in a custom directive. The following is a sample snippet:

```
myModule.directive("testDirective", ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            obj: '=testDirective',
            defaultValue: '@default',
            placeholder: '@placeholder'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var input = $($compile('<input required placeholder="{{placeholder}}" value="{{defaultValue}}" />')(scope));

            element.append(input);
            ...
            ...
```

For some reason the "required" attribute does not function correctly when applied to the "input" inside this custom directive. Looking through the source, it appears to fail here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/600e6218fedd03bffabf78a9f7d0d9b68515b9a3/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1319. The "ctrl" variable is undefined.

When I apply the "require" attribute to elements outside of this (or any other) custom directive, everything works fine (ie: the ctrl variable is populated correctly). Just curious if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: required should be used with `ngModel` , please describe what your directive should do